# ¿Como combino html y php en la función mail()?

Tags: php, html

Buenas, quisiera saber como envió un mail que sea mixto entre php y html como este:

```
$from = "Ganadores@prueba.com";
$to = $correito; 
$subject = 'Ganaste la oferta por un producto';

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
$headers .= "From: Prueba<$from>\r\n";

$msg = '
      <html>
        <head>
          <h1>PRUEBA</h1>
        </head>
     <body>
     <strong>Felicidades por ganar la subasta de: <?php echo $obj_subasta ?> </strong>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es importante entender que un cliente de correo si "entiende" `HTML`, pero no `PHP`. Lo que tienes que hacer es mandarle todo en `HTML` para que lo entienda. Esto se puede conseguir si concatenas tus variables en `PHP` a lo que ya tienes en `HTML`. Algo asi:

```
$from = "Ganadores@prueba.com";
$to = $correito; 
$subject = 'Ganaste la oferta por un producto';

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
$headers .= "From: Prueba<".$from.">\r\n";

$msg = '
      <html>
        <head>
          <h1>PRUEBA</h1>
        </head>
     <body>
     <strong>Felicidades por ganar la subasta de: '.$obj_subasta.' </strong>
    </body>
```

P.D. Supongo que `$obj_subasta` es otra de tus variables de `PHP`, aunque no este en tu código.

Comment: en efecto! Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Si te fijas, **tienes un error en el código**, a la hora de componer el mensaje. Estas abriendo un bloque de código PHP y haciendo un *echo*, dentro de tu código PHP. Corrección:

```
$msg = '<html><head>
   <h1>PRUEBA</h1>
   </head><body>
   <strong>Felicidades por ganar la subasta de: ' . $obj_subasta . '</strong>
   </body>';
```